Sub Worksheet_Change not triggered using dropdown
thanks in advance for your help.
I am trying to get a Sub worksheet_change to trigger when the value in B2 is changed using a vlookup formula from a dropdown in A2.
When I manually type a supplier number into B2 it triggers and list fine, but when I use the dropdown it will not fire.
Dropdown in A2 is my supplier name, B2 would have a vlookup formula, this is the cell I need to trigger the worksheet change.
The below is the code that I currently have and is working 100% accurate if I manually input.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  
With Target
        
    If .Address = "$B$2" And Len(.Cells(1).Value) > 0 Then

            Dim objDic As Object, rngData As Range
            Dim i As Long, sKey As String, sSupp As String
            Dim lastRow As Long, arrData
            Dim oSht1 As Worksheet

            Set oSht1 = Sheets("WRICFY")
            sSupp = .Value

            lastRow = oSht1.Cells(oSht1.Rows.Count, "Z").End(xlUp).Row
            Set rngData = oSht1.Range("D1:Z" & lastRow)

            arrData = rngData.Value

            Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

            For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
                sKey = arrData(i, 1) ' Col D [Supplier]

                If StrComp(sSupp, sKey, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                    objDic(arrData(i, 23)) = ""
                End If
            Next i

            ' Write Product list to sheet
            lastRow = Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

            Application.EnableEvents = False
            If lastRow > 15 Then Me.Range("A21:A" & lastRow).ClearContents

            If objDic.Count > 0 Then Me.Range("A21").Resize(objDic.Count, 1) = 
Application.Transpose(objDic.keys)

            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub


"B2 would have a vlookup formula" - you need to use worksheet_calculate and not the change event.  Worksheet_Change isn't triggered by cells with formulas

Or check for Target.Address = "$A$1" in the change event, and grab the lookup result from B2

Thanks Tim, I am not real good with code at all, in fact I would be nowhere if it wasnt for this page.  Where do I put the change in the code?

At the moment the vlookup is putting the result in B2, user has to manually input it then into B1, the manual input is what I am trying to elimate

Sorry I meant capture the change event for the cell with the drop-down. A2 not A1
